# In Before the Flood, why open the Faraday cage?

Tags: doctor-who

In Doctor Who episode *Before the Flood*, the Doctor’s

> ghost

does 3 things:

1. Repeats the names of the crew in the order in which they will die
2. Delivers the “chamber will open tonight” message
3. Opens the Faraday cage

I understood 1 and 2: 1 so that the Doctor would be compelled to break the rules of time (or whatever) to save Clara; and 2 so as to give himself the idea of entering the suspended animation chamber.

But why did he open the Faraday cage? What did that achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the start of the episode the Doctor talks about the "Bootstrap Paradox" which put at very basic level essentially refers to someone using knowledge of future events to create said events in the first place. This becomes important at the end of the episode where he referred to this paradox when he explained to Clara that he created his hologram making it say and do what it did because he had seen the ghost in the future, so if the Doctor's creation was inspired by the fact of its existence what brought about this existence in the first place? I think the suggestion was the Doctor had died in the past which created a real ghost which then inspired him to create his hologram, this suggestion would then explain why it opened the Faraday Cage to release the other ghosts which the Doctor kept in the hologram to preserve the sequence of events in the timeline.

Comment: +1. TL;DR: because Clara told The Doctor his ghost opened the cage. Now it had to do it.